# how to have recyclerview horizontal imageview share a side like a carousel

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview set up with a linear layout at horizontal where each imageview takes up the full width of the visible recyclerview. I was wondering how to fix this such that the imageview items are next to each other the way you'd see this in a carousel. A copy of what I'm seeing is found below. [image]Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your layout item, which you are inflating using the adapter class.. you should define the width of the layout as either `wrap_content` or a fixed value(for eg: 200dp or something else according to your need). I think you have used `match_parent` that's why you are facing such an issue.

**Feel free to ask if something is unclear.**

Comment: thank you! btw, this was from following the tutorial here https://www.androidauthority.com/how-to-build-an-image-gallery-app-718976/ which used a grid layout. I made a couple changes but completely overlooked that cell_layout had its width set to match_parent as well as its imageview child

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the ImageView has been resized based on the `layout_height` specified and you have a value of `wrap_content` on the `layout_width`. You should set the ImageView's attribute `android:adjustViewBounds` to `true`.

Reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView#attr_android:adjustViewBounds